# Override plugin class which has namespace

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, pluggable, namespace

I would like to override this plugin class in child theme :

**class-config.php**

```
namespace um;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

if ( ! class_exists( 'um\Config' ) ) {


    /**
     * Class Config
     *
     * Class with global variables for UM
     *
     * @package um
     */
    class Config
    {
        //some code here...
    }
    //end class
}
```

But as you can see, this class uses a namespace, so I can't just write this in my functions.php :

**functions.php**

```
class Config
{
    //some new code here...
}
```

I tried to add *namespace um;* in functions.php but of course it doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it ! :)

I just created **another file** called class-config-new.php just next to functions.php. I wrote my class in class-config-new.php and added the namespace, and I added a require_once in functions.php to call the file.